# Google Cloud Load Balancer --path-rules command "no matches found"

Tags: cloud, zsh, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm currently following the [Content Based Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/content-based-example) guide over at Google and I'm currently stuck on step 4b. The step asks me to add a path matcher to my URL map and define my request path mappings. To do this, I must use the gcloud command:

```
gcloud compute url-maps add-path-matcher web-map \
    --default-service web-map-backend-service --path-matcher-name pathmap \
    --path-rules=/video=video-service,/video/*=video-service,/static=static-service,/static/*=static-service
```

When I type this into my terminal client, I get the error:

> zsh: no matches found:
>   --path-rules=/video=video-service,/video/*=video-service,/static=static-service,/static/*=static-service

Here's an image of what I submit and the error I get: [gcloud path-rules error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrqnP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably zsh interpreting the flags wrong. The guides were most likely tested with bash.

I think zsh is trying to do something special with * in the --path-rules argument.

Please use quotes for your arguments to be sure zsh interprets the arguments correctly. Does this work?

```
  gcloud compute url-maps add-path-matcher web-map \
    --default-service web-map-backend-service --path-matcher-name pathmap \
    --path-rules '/video=video-service,/video/*=video-service,/static=static-service,/static/*=static-service'
```